# How to performance test MongoDB Storage Engine for website Session data?

Tags: mongodb, session, performance-testing

I'm looking to utilize MongoDB for session data storage, so we don't need sticky sessions in our load balanced environment.

As of 3.0, we can use different storage engines within MongoDB.
While MMapV1 and WiredTiger come out of the box, it's also possible to run other storage engines (RocksDB?).

What I would like to do is test out my website using MongoDB with the different storage engines backed behind it.
I currently have a JMeter script that will hit multiple pages on the site for many different users.

Between tests I can switch out the Mongo connection, to different Mongod instances on different storage engines.
All I can really take out of this is the average latency for the page loads in JMeter.

Is there better results I can find, possibly using different tools or techniques?
Or, for session data, which is heavily read/write, is there one storage engine that would be preferred over another?

I'm not sure if this question is too open-ended or not, but I thought I'd ask here to maybe get more direction about how to test this out.

Answer (score 1):

An important advantage of WiredTiger over the default MMAP storage engine is that while MMAP locks the whole collection for a write, WiredTiger locks only the affected document(s). That means multiple users can change multiple documents at the same time. This is especially interesting in your case of session data, because you will likely have many website visitors at the same time, each one regularly updating their own session document. But when you want to test if this feature really provides a benefit in your use-case, you will have to build a more sophisticated test setup which simulates many simultaneous updates and requests from multiple users.

Another interesting feature of WiredTiger is that it compresses both data and indexes, which greatly reduces filesize. But this feature does of course cost performance. So when you only want to compare performance, you should switch off compression to have a fair comparison. The relevant config keys are:

```
storage.wiredTiger.collectionConfig.blockCompressor = none
storage.wiredTiger.indexConfig.prefixCompression = false
```

Keep in mind that changes to these keys will only take effect on newly created collections and indexes.

Another factor which could skew your results is cache size. The MMAP engine always uses all the RAM it can get to cache data. But WiredTiger is far more conservative and only uses half of the available RAM, unless you set a different value in

```
storage.wiredTiger.engineConfig.cacheSizeGB
```

So when you want a fair comparision, you should set this to the RAM size of the machine it runs on, minus the ram required by other processes running on the same machine. But this will of course only make a difference when your test uses more test data than fits into memory, so that the cache handling of both engines starts to matter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think turning off compression will help, because the session data really doesn't need to be compressed. I even wondered about the experimental In Memory storage engine.... because in the end I don't require the sessions to be persisted if the working set can entirely be in memory. (my app cleans this up anyway at the end of a session).
Thanks for the tips.